# How to build a predict function with Lasso and RobustScalar?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I'm trying to figure out how to predict values with LASSO regression without using the `.predict` function that Sklearn provides. This is basically just to broaden my understanding of how LASSO works internally. I asked a question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421841/is-it-possible-to-calculate-lasso-by-hand) about how LASSO regression works, and one of the comments mentioned how the predict function works the same as in Linear Regression. Because of this, I wanted to try and make my own function to do this.

I was able to successfully recreate the predict function in simpler examples, but when I try to use it in conjunction with `RobustScaler`, I keep getting different outputs. With this example, I'm getting the prediction as 4.33 with Sklearn, and 6.18 with my own function. What am I missing here? Am I not inverse transforming the prediction correctly at the end?

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[5, -10, 10, .5, 2.5, 15], 'X1':[1., -2.,  2., .1, .5, 3], 'X2':[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], 
              'X3':[6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4], 'X4':[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})

X = df[['X1','X2','X3','X4']]
y = df[['Y']]

#Scaling 
transformer_x = RobustScaler().fit(X)
transformer_y = RobustScaler().fit(y) 
X_scal = transformer_x.transform(X)
y_scal = transformer_y.transform(y)

#LASSO
lasso = Lasso()
lasso = lasso.fit(X_scal, y_scal)

#LASSO info
print('Score: ', lasso.score(X_scal,y_scal))
print('Raw Intercept: ', lasso.intercept_.round(2)[0]) 
intercept = transformer_y.inverse_transform([lasso.intercept_])[0][0]
print('Unscaled Intercept: ', intercept) 
print('\nCoefficients Used: ')
coeff_array = lasso.coef_
inverse_coeff_array = transformer_x.inverse_transform(lasso.coef_.reshape(1,-1))[0]
for i,j,k in zip(X.columns, coeff_array, inverse_coeff_array):
    if j != 0:
        print(i, j.round(2), k.round(2))

#Predictions
example = [[3,1,1,1]]
pred = lasso.predict(example)
pred_scal = transformer_y.inverse_transform(pred.reshape(-1, 1))
print('\nRaw Prediction where X1 = 3: ', pred[0])
print('Unscaled Prediction where X1 = 3: ', pred_scal[0][0])

#Predictions without using the .predict function 
def lasso_predict_value_(X1,X2,X3,X4): 
    print('intercept: ', intercept)
    print('coef: ', inverse_coeff_array[0])
    print('X1: ', X1)
    preds = intercept + inverse_coeff_array[0]*X1
    print('Your predicted value is: ', preds)

lasso_predict_value_(3,1,1,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trained `Lasso` does not have any information whether the given datapoint is scalled or not. Hence your manual method to do the predict should not take the scalling aspect of it.

If I remove your processing on the model co-efficients, we can get the result of sklearn model

```
example = [[3,1,1,1]]
lasso.predict(example)

# array([0.07533937])


#Predictions without using the .predict function 
def lasso_predict_value_(X1,X2,X3,X4): 
    x_test = np.array([X1,X2, X3, X4])
    preds = lasso.intercept_ + sum(x_test*lasso.coef_)
    print('Your predicted value is: ', preds)


lasso_predict_value_(3,1,1,1)

# Your predicted value is:  [0.07533937]
```

## Update 2:

> Once I use LASSO, I then need to see what my predictions were in their
>   original units. My dependent variable is in dollar amounts, and if I
>   don't inverse transform it back, I'm unable to see how many dollars I
>   need for the prediction.

This is a very valid scenario. You need to apply the `transformer_y.inverse_transform` to get your unscalled dollar amount value. There is no need for disturbing the model weights.

Updated example

```
example = [[3,1,1,1]]
scaled_pred = lasso.predict(transformer_x.transform(example))
transformer_y.inverse_transform([scaled_pred])
# array([[4.07460407]])

#Predictions without using the .predict function 
def lasso_predict_value_(X1,X2,X3,X4): 
    x_test = transformer_x.transform(np.array([X1,X2, X3, X4]).reshape(1,-1))[0]
    preds = lasso.intercept_ + sum(x_test*lasso.coef_)
    print('Your predicted value is: ', preds)
    print('Your unscaled predicted value is: ', 
          transformer_y.inverse_transform([scaled_pred]))


lasso_predict_value_(3,1,1,1)
# Your predicted value is:  [0.0418844]    
# Your unscaled predicted value is:  [[4.07460407]]
```

Comment: So I know how to do this part already. How do I do this with scaled data?

Comment: scale the data and then apply the model coeffs. Please find my updated answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not being clear. I want to unscale the prediction at the end, which is why I was using inverse_transform in my code, but was getting different results. How do I predict the future values with LASSO, on the scaled data, and then unscale the predicted value at the end?

Comment: Also, side note. I see you're using transformer_x to scale the predictions. I've been using transformer_y, which was recommended to be in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169286/how-to-inverse-transform-regression-predictions-after-lasso-and-robustscalar) question. Should I be using transformer_x instead?

Comment: you should not do inverse transform of model co-effs and it is not possible as well becuase `transformer_x` will take 4 dimensional input only. This gives you the reason why you can't do inverse transform of intercept. I think you are confusing too much. I have added the code for doing prediction using scaled data. If you need unscaled value, then apply `transformer_y.inverse_transform` on the prediction. Still if you are not clear, give the reason for converting the model coeffs. otherwise you can fit the model on unscaled data itself. Hope it gives you some clarity.

Comment: So it's just not possible to do the inverse transform of the coefficients or the intercept of a LASSO model? I need to scale the data before I fit the model simply because my data is not normalized, and LASSO performs very poorly on it when it is not scaled. Once I use LASSO, I then need to see what my predictions were in their original units. My dependent variable is in dollar amounts, and if I don't inverse transform it back, I'm unable to see how many dollars I need for the prediction.

Comment: yes, there is no way to get the inverse transform for intercept values. Please find my updated answer for your next point. Kindly review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)