# Can I inverse transform the intercept and coefficients of LASSO regression after using Robust Scaler?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lasso-regression

Is it possible to inverse transform the intercept and coefficients in LASSO regression, after fitting the model on scaled data using Robust Scaler?

I'm using LASSO regression to predict values on data that is not normalized and doesn't perform well with LASSO unless it's scaled beforehand. After scaling the data and fitting the LASSO model, I ideally want to be able to see what the model intercept and coefficients are but in the original units (not the scaled versions). I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497758/how-to-build-a-predict-function-with-lasso-and-robustscalar/57499692#57499692) and it doesn't appear this is possible. If not, why? Can someone explain this to me? I'm trying to broaden my understanding of how LASSO and Robust Scaler work.

Below is the code I was using. Here I was trying to inverse transform the coefficients using transformer_x and the intercept using transformer_y. However, it sounds like this is incorrect.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[5, -10, 10, .5, 2.5, 15], 'X1':[1., -2.,  2., .1, .5, 3], 'X2':[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], 
              'X3':[6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4], 'X4':[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})

X = df[['X1','X2', 'X3' ,'X4']]
y = df[['Y']]

#Scaling 
transformer_x = RobustScaler().fit(X)
transformer_y = RobustScaler().fit(y) 
X_scal = transformer_x.transform(X)
y_scal = transformer_y.transform(y)

#LASSO
lasso = Lasso()
lasso = lasso.fit(X_scal, y_scal)

def pred_val(X1,X2,X3,X4): 

    print('X1 entered: ', X1)

    #Scale X value that user entered - by hand
    med_X = X.median()
    Q1_X = X.quantile(0.25)
    Q3_X = X.quantile(0.75)
    IQR_X = Q3_X - Q1_X
    X_scaled = (X1 - med_X)/IQR_X
    print('X1 scaled by hand: ', X_scaled[0].round(2))

    #Scale X value that user entered - by function
    X_scaled2 = transformer_x.transform(np.array([[X1,X2]]))
    print('X1 scaled by function: ', X_scaled2[0][0].round(2))

    #Intercept by hand
    med_y = y.median()
    Q1_y = y.quantile(0.25)
    Q3_y = y.quantile(0.75)
    IQR_y = Q3_y - Q1_y
    inv_int = med_y + IQR_y*lasso.intercept_[0]

    #Intercept by function
    inv_int2 = transformer_y.inverse_transform(lasso.intercept_.reshape(-1, 1))[0][0]

    #Coefficient by hand
    inv_coef = lasso.coef_[0]*IQR_y 

    #Coefficient by function 
    inv_coef2 = transformer_x.inverse_transform(reg.coef_.reshape(1,-1))[0]

    #Prediction by hand
    preds = inv_int + inv_coef*X_scaled[0]

    #Prediction by function 
    preds_inner = lasso.predict(X_scaled2)  
    preds_f = transformer_y.inverse_transform(preds_inner.reshape(-1, 1))[0][0]

    print('\nIntercept by hand: ', inv_int[0].round(2))
    print('Intercept by function: ', inv_int2.round(2))
    print('\nCoefficients by hand: ', inv_coef[0].round(2))
    print('Coefficients by function: ', inv_coef2[0].round(2))
    print('\nYour predicted value by hand is: ', preds[0].round(2))
    print('Your predicted value by function is: ', preds_f.round(2))
    print('Perfect Prediction would be 80')

pred_val(10,1,1,1)
```

**Update**: I've updated my code to show the type of prediction function I'm trying to create. I'm just trying to create a function that does exactly what `.predict` does, but also shows the intercept and coefficients in their unscaled units.

Current output:

```
Out[1]:
X1 entered:  10
X1 scaled by hand:  5.97
X1 scaled by function:  5.97

Intercept by hand:  34.19
Intercept by function:  34.19

Coefficients by hand:  7.6
Coefficients by function:  8.5

Your predicted value by hand is:  79.54
Your predicted value by function is:  79.54
Perfect Prediction would be 80
```

Ideal output:

```
Out[1]:
X1 entered:  10
X1 scaled by hand:  5.97
X1 scaled by function:  5.97

Intercept by hand:  34.19
Intercept by function:  34.19

Coefficients by hand:  7.6
Coefficients by function:  7.6

Your predicted value by hand is:  79.54
Your predicted value by function is:  79.54
Perfect Prediction would be 80
```

Comment: To clarify: do you want the coefficients and intercept in original units, or do you want the prediction in original units (like in Stergios' answer)?

Comment: I want the coefficients and intercept in the original units

Comment: Like, if you have predicted values in USD and X values are in [yr, m^2, USD] (for example) you want the coefficients in USD/yr, USD/m^2 and pure number, and intercept in USD?

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your question. I want the coefficients in their original units, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the linked SO thread, all you want to do is to get the unscaled prediction value. Is that right?

If yes, then all you need to do is:

```
# Scale the test dataset
X_test_scaled = transformer_x.transform(X_test)

# Predict with the trained model
prediction = lasso.predict(X_test_scaled)

# Inverse transform the prediction
prediction_in_dollars = transformer_y.inverse_transform(prediction)
```

UPDATE:

Suppose the train data contain just a single feature named `X`. Here is what the RobustScaler will do:

```
X_scaled = (X - median(X))/IQR(X)
y_scaled = (y - median(y))/IQR(y)
```

Then, the lasso regression will give a prediction like this:

```
a * X_scaled + b = y_scaled
```

You have to work out the equations to see what model coefficient on the unscaled data:

```
# Substituting X_scaled and y_scaled from the 1st equation
# In this equation `median(X), IQR(X), median(y) and IQR(y) are plain numbers you already know from the training phase
a * (X - median(X))/IQR(X) + b = (y - median(y))/IQR(y)
```

If you try to make a `a_new * x + b_new = y`-like equation out of this, you end up with:

```
a_new = (a * (X - median(X)) / (X * IQR(X))) * IQR(y)
b_new = b * IQR(y) + median(y)
a_new * X + b_new = y
```

You can see that the unscaled coefficient (`a_new`) depends on `X`. So, you can use the unscaled `X` to make predictions directly but in between you are applying the transformation indirectly.

UPDATE 2

I've adapted your code and it now shows how you can get the coefficients in the original scale. The script is just the implementation of the formulas I'm showing above.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[5, -10, 10, .5, 2.5, 15], 'X1':[1., -2.,  2., .1, .5, 3], 'X2':[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
              'X3':[6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4], 'X4':[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})

X = df[['X1','X2','X3','X4']]
y = df[['Y']]

#Scaling
transformer_x = RobustScaler().fit(X)
transformer_y = RobustScaler().fit(y)
X_scal = transformer_x.transform(X)
y_scal = transformer_y.transform(y)

#LASSO
lasso = Lasso()
lasso = lasso.fit(X_scal, y_scal)

def pred_val(X_test):

    print('X entered: ',)
    print (X_test.values[0])

    #Scale X value that user entered - by hand
    med_X = X.median()
    Q1_X = X.quantile(0.25)
    Q3_X = X.quantile(0.75)
    IQR_X = Q3_X - Q1_X
    X_scaled = ((X_test - med_X)/IQR_X).fillna(0).values
    print('X_test scaled by hand: ',)
    print (X_scaled[0])

    #Scale X value that user entered - by function
    X_scaled2 = transformer_x.transform(X_test)
    print('X_test scaled by function: ',)
    print (X_scaled2[0])

    #Intercept by hand
    med_y = y.median()
    Q1_y = y.quantile(0.25)
    Q3_y = y.quantile(0.75)
    IQR_y = Q3_y - Q1_y

    a = lasso.coef_
    coef_new = ((a * (X_test - med_X).values) / (X_test * IQR_X).values) * float(IQR_y)
    coef_new = np.nan_to_num(coef_new)[0]

    b = lasso.intercept_[0]
    intercept_new = b * float(IQR_y) + float(med_y)

    custom_pred = sum((coef_new * X_test.values)[0]) + intercept_new

    pred = lasso.predict(X_scaled2)
    final_pred = transformer_y.inverse_transform(pred.reshape(-1, 1))[0][0]


    print('Original intercept: ', lasso.intercept_[0].round(2))
    print('New intercept: ', intercept_new.round(2))
    print('Original coefficients: ', lasso.coef_.round(2))
    print('New coefficients: ', coef_new.round(2))
    print('Your predicted value by function is: ', final_pred.round(2))
    print('Your predicted value by hand is: ', custom_pred.round(2))


X_test = pd.DataFrame([10,1,1,1]).T
X_test.columns = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4']

pred_val(X_test)
```

You can see the the custom prediction uses the original values (`X_test.values`).

Result:

```
X entered: 
[10  1  1  1]

X_test scaled by hand: 
[ 5.96774194  0.         -6.66666667 -1.        ]
X_test scaled by function: 
[ 5.96774194  0.         -6.66666667 -1.        ]

Original intercept:  0.01
New intercept:  3.83

Original coefficients:  [ 0.02  0.   -0.   -0.  ]
New coefficients:  [0.1 0.  0.  0. ]

Your predicted value by function is:  4.83
Your predicted value by hand is:  4.83
```

As I explained above, the new coefficients depend on `X_test`. This means that you cannot use their current values with another test sample. Their values will be different for different inputs.

Comment: I'm looking to get the coefficients and intercept in the original units, not the predicted value.

Comment: Once I get the unscaled coefficients and intercept, can I then predict values by y = unscaled_intercept + (unscaled_coef * X_unscaled) ?

Comment: Please check my answer above showing how you can do this. By the way, why do you want to inverse the coefficients? What's the end goal?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I checked your answer and I'm still unsure of how to unscale the coefficients. When I do lasso.coef_*IQR_y I get very different coefficients than from my original inverse_coeff_array, which uses the inverse_transform function. Why is this? (Also, my end goal here is to simply see how LASSO is predicting values, which is made rather difficult to see when also using RobustScaler)

Comment: Using `inverse_transform ()` on the coefficients does not make sense. The `inverse_transform()` can only be applied to the data, not the model coefficients. Anyway, `inverse_transform()` is actually doing `(X * IQR(X)) + median(X)`, so it's not only  `X * IQR(X)`.

Comment: To be honest, I still don't really understand why you want to inverse the coefficients. However, the equations I've written above should help you.

Comment: You said applying ```inverse_transform()``` on the coefficients doesn't make sense. Is there no way to see the coefficients in their original units then using ```inverse_transform()```? My end goal here is just to build a function to predict LASSO values with RobustScaler, without using the pre-built ```.predict``` function. To do this, I was hoping to do something like y = unscaled_intercept + (unscaled_coef * X_unscaled) , which is why I'm so interested in the unscaled versions of the coefficients and intercept.

Comment: Yes, you cannot use `inverse_transform()` for the coefficients. If you want to predict on new data without using the `.predict()` method, you need to scale the new data (`x_scaled = transformer_x.transform(x)`) and then you can use the LASSO coefficients and the intercept and manually apply the regression function (i.e. `prediction = lasso.intercept_ + lasso.coef_[0] * x_scaled[0] + ...`). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Like my original question is asking, if it is not possible to use inverse_transform() with the coefficients, why is that?

Comment: I updated my code and showed exactly what type of output I'm looking for to hopefully make it more clear :)

Comment: I've updated my answer above and adapted your code.

Comment: In the updated code I posted, I was unable to get the unscaled coefficients I was calculating by hand to equal the unscaled coefficients I was trying to create with ```inverse_transform()```. It looks like your code doesn't try to unscale the coefficients with ```inverse_transform()```. Again, if this is not possible to do, why not? Why do I have different numbers (i.e. 7.6 and 8.5)?

Comment: You cannot use `inverse_transform()` because this formula is incorrect. That's why I'm not using it. The correct formulas are shown above in my post. The unscaled coefficients should be calculated with this formula `(old_coef * (X_test - median(X)) / (X_test * IQR(X))) * IQR(y)` and not by `(old_coef * IQR(X)) + median(X)`. These formulas are different and the former one is the correct one. That's why you cannot use `inverse_transform()`.

Comment: With my previous update in the code I have answered your question which was to "create a function that does exactly what .predict does, but also shows the intercept and coefficients in their unscaled units". Notice that the `custom_pred` uses the original `X_test` values and not the scaled ones.

Comment: If I have answered your question, please accept my answer.

Comment: @Stergios There seems to be a mistake in your formula.  First, a_new shouldn't depend on X. The first substitution step is correct, but one must expand all terms, and identify the new a (a_new) as whatever multiplies x.  Everything else is b_new.